# Nominatim with osm2pgsql for rhel 6

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, nominatim

I tried configure&make Nominatim on rhel6.5 but Nominatim compiled whithout osm2pgsql. I also tried complied osm2pgql by handle with ./autogen, ./configure make and got many errors
like:

> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
>   make[1]: *** [osm2pgsql] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/Nominatim/osm2pgsql'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

After local instalation boost-1.58 I got osm2pgsl but now when I trying ./setup.php like:

> service postgresql-9.3 start && sudo -u nominatim -- ./utils/setup.php --osm-file maps/switzerland.osm.bz2 --all --threads 2 2>&1

I got error bellow:

> Import
>   /opt/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   ERROR: Error executing external command: /opt/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 2507 -P 5432 -d nominatim /opt/Nominatim/maps/switzerland.osm.bz2
>   Error executing external command: /opt/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 2507 -P 5432 -d nominatim /opt/Nominatim/maps/switzerland.osm.bz2

Is there prepared osm2pgsql for rhel 6.5 or where I can find default.style for Nominatim like bases that use osm2pgsql by handle?

- autogen

> ./autogen.sh
>   [root@nominatim osm2pgsql]# ./autogen.sh
>   autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
>   autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
>   autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
>   autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
>   autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
>   libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in`.'.
>   libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
>   libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR,`m4'.
>   libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
>   libtoolize: copying file`m4/ltoptions.m4'
>   libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
>   libtoolize: copying file`m4/ltversion.m4'
>   libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
>   autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
>   autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
>   autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
>   autoreconf: Leaving directory`.'

- configure

```
 [root@nominatim osm2pgsql]# ./configure
checking whether to disable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for g++... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for lseek64... yes
checking for posix_fallocate... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... yes
checking for sync_file_range... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking for xml2 libraries... yes
checking for zlib headers in /usr/include... found
checking for zlib library... found
checking for zlib compression library... yes
checking for bzip2 headers in /usr/include... found
checking for bzip2 library... found
checking for bzip2 compression library... yes
checking for geos-config... /usr/bin/geos-config
checking for geos libraries... checking geos/version.h usability... yes
checking geos/version.h presence... yes
checking for geos/version.h... yes
yes
checking if geos version is >= 3.1... yes
checking for proj headers in /usr/include... found
checking for proj library... found
checking for proj projection library... yes
checking for protobuf-c 0.14...
checking for protobuf_c headers in /usr/include... found
checking for protobuf_c library... found
checking for protobuf-c version >= 0.14...
checking for ProtobufCFieldDescriptor.packed... yes
protobuf-c >= 0.14: yes
checking for protobuf-c usability... yes
checking for protoc-c... /usr/bin/protoc-c
checking for pg_config... /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for PostgreSQL libraries... yes
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for boostlib >= 1.48... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.53... yes
checking for a Lua interpreter with version >= 5.0... lua
checking for lua... /usr/bin/lua
checking for lua version... 5.1
checking for lua platform... unknown
checking for lua script directory... ${prefix}/share/lua/5.1
checking for lua module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/lua/5.1
checking if LUA_VERSION is defined... yes
checking lua.h usability... yes
checking lua.h presence... yes
checking for lua.h... yes
checking lualib.h usability... yes
checking lualib.h presence... yes
checking for lualib.h... yes
checking lauxlib.h usability... yes
checking lauxlib.h presence... yes
checking for lauxlib.h... yes
checking luaconf.h usability... yes
checking luaconf.h presence... yes
checking for luaconf.h... yes
checking for Lua header version... 5.1
checking if Lua header version matches 5.1... yes
checking if LUA_VERSION is defined... yes
checking for library containing exp... -lm
checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl
checking for library containing lua_load... -llua-5.1
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

```
enter code here
```

- make out :

> ./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(osmdata.o): In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
>   /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:179: undefined reference to`boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
>   /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:179: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
>   ./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(osmdata.o): In function`boost::thread::join()':
>   /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:767: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
>   ./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(osmdata.o): In function`boost::thread::start_thread()':
>   /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:179: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[1]: *** [osm2pgsql] Error 1
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: The output of your first error message is cropped, the most important part is missing.

Comment: I've added output

Comment: Hmm, `undefined reference` could indicate a problem with the boost version you are using. Maybe an older version will work.

Comment: You mean 1.48<=boost version<1.58 ?